# Way to set a file as a Nautilus Bookmark?

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus allows user to set a Folder as a bookmark.

I want to set a text file (that opens in Gedit) as a bookmark that will appear in the sidepane. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. You definitely cannot add a file as a bookmark from the GUI.

Nautilus bookmarks are stored in `~/.gtk-bookmarks`.  I tried manually adding a path to a text file to that file.  The text file showed up in the side pane in Nautilus, but clicking on it opened the folder containing the text file.

Comment: You used to be able to do it in GNOME-2 by creating a bookmark of the folder the file is in and then "editing bookmark" and adding the /filename.ext at the end of the folder's bookmark. But this is no longer working. It would be so convenient to bookmark a file. Using DASH to search often does not find the file I seek so I have to manually rummage through folders to find what i want.

Comment: It is definitely a shame this doesn't work anymore.  I was looking to do the same thing recently and was not successful.

I believe the file search in the Dash uses Zeitgeist to search for files, so it will only find files that you have opened recently.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with DASH/Zeitgeist, but there are some files it never finds even if I open them ;( using 12.04

Comment: I used to use [this](https://launchpad.net/filesearch-lens) file search lens, but it hasn't been updated since 11.10.

Comment: You could also try checking your Zeitgeist settings to see if it's disabled.  Search for "Privacy" in the dash to open the settings.